# How to check if checkbox is checked in other page

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

I have 2 pages. EditEventTicketsInfo.aspx and SummaryEvent.aspx

 
For EditEventTicketsInfo.aspx

```
<tr>
   <td style="width:170px;" ><div style="margin-top:-5px;">
    <div class="form-label">
      <span>Hide Package Information</span>:
    </div>
    </div>
   </td>
   <td class="test_cb_td"><div style="width:205px;"><div style="margin-top:-5px;">
      <div style="float:left;"><asp:CheckBox ID="chkHidePackage" AutoPostback="true" runat="server" checked="false" class="test_cb"></asp:CheckBox></div>
      </div>
   </td>
```

```
 <asp:Label runat="server" id="pkg_visibility">
   <tbody id="pkg_container">
     <%=Packages%>
    </tbody>
</asp:Label>
```

Below is the script for hiding the  <%=Packages%>

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.test_cb_td .test_cb .jqTransformCheckboxWrapper').find('.jqTransformCheckbox').click(function () {
            if ($('[id$=_chkHidePackage]').attr('checked')) {
                $('[id$=_chkHidePackage]').attr('checked', true);
                $("#pkg_visibility").val('');
                $("#pkg_container").attr("style", "visibility: hidden")
            } else {
                $('[id$=_chkHidePackage]').attr('checked', false);
                $("#pkg_container").attr("style", "visibility: visible")                }
        });
    });
```

This code is working as expected in EditEventTicketsInfo.aspx.
Now I want to check if chkHidePackage is checked, then hide the same value in SummaryEvent.aspx. Help please.

Comment: You could store it as a cookie, or persist it through the session if you're doing a postback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a boolean or an int variable 
and place a if block and in condition checking, check if the check box is checked if the condition appears to be true change the value of variable from 0 to 1 and in later page where you want to check if the check box is checked, check if the value of the variable has changed from 0 to 1 if yes then the check box is checked else its unchecked!

Answer (score 0):

You can handle checked change event of your checkBox and then put value of checkstate in a session.

How hard was that?

Answer (score 0):

You can complete this task in many way.

You can use [Session variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx), [Cookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.cookies.aspx), [Query string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524784%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

*Just set or pass the value of checkbox like if it's checked set or pass a boolean value true else false and then check that value in second page and apply the logic*.

Hope you understand.